# Cancel password reset in Laravel if $user->save() fails

Tags: php, laravel

The default postReset() action of the Reminder controller has the following code for resetting the password:

```
$response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) 
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
});
```

I want to add a condition to cancel the reset if the save method fails (for any reason). My models call a validate function on the saving() event, so $user->save() returns false if the fields don't validate.

I have modified my code to this:

```
$response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) 
{
    $user->password = $password;

    # validate before password hashing
    if(!$user->validate()) {
        Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Validator failed');
        return false;
    }

    # hash password and try to save
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    if(!$user->save()) {
        Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Validator failed');
        return false;
    }
});

if (!$response) {
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Validator failed');
}
```

But I see that the return of the closure does not affect the $response variable... so any ideas how to do this?

Comment: How are you testing/emulating a failed save? (also, top code block is missing a semicolon)

Comment: I am posting a passwords that won't validate. I have defined the validation rules on the User model, and I put a die() on the validator->fails(), and I see that it does not validate

Comment: What is your validation rule to password? What passwords do you submit?

Comment: The validation rule is at least 8 chars, and I am submitting passwords with less

Comment: `$response` is always non-false because of [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/254497b8672e90ca6ee562a3d1fe9eab540daabe/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders/PasswordBroker.php#L179). Probably, you are using `Password` facade in wrong manner. Or try to use exception throwing instead of `return`

Comment: the exception throwing with try catch did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this with throwing an exception, as per [neoascetic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798594/cancel-password-reset-in-laravel-if-user-save-fails#comment34817024_22798594):

```
try {
    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        if(!$user->save()) {
            # throw exception if save fails
            throw new Exception(Password::INVALID_PASSWORD);
        }
    });
} catch ( Exception $e) {
    $response = Password::INVALID_PASSWORD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User saving doesn't mean it will be validated (if you use vanilla Laravel, of course). You need to validate user by your hands before saving and redirect back with error on **validation** fail, not on **saving** fail. I. e. you need to use code like this:

```
if($validator->fails() || !$user->save())
{
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Failed to save');
}
```

Where `$validator` is instance of Validator with your rules.

Comment: yes but I have a validation on the saving(), creating() and updating() events, so save() should return false if it does not validate